# Building dynamic linear model in R with dlm package, MLE and Bayesian inference for parameter estimation

Tags: r, time-series

Here's the background. I have a time series representing daily sales. And I had built some models, like, ARIMA (`arima`), STL Decomposition (`stl`), Holt-winter (`hw`), and exponential smoothing state space model (result from the `ets` reduced to a `hw` model, because the returned model showed additive error/trend/seasonality), etc.

Anyway, the data is non-stationary, representing trend and weekly seasonality, which can also be proved with spectral analysis/periodogram. By using cross validation of 1-step to 15-step ahead forecast, I found stl decomposition gave me the best result in MAE.

Then, I started working on a dynamic linear model to see if I can build a better one for forecasting. The model is also written in R, with `dlm`, which is local linear + seasonal + ARMA model, and the code as below

```
build <- function(parm) {
    level0 <- 20
    slope0 <- 1
    # Level + Trend
    trend <- dlmModPoly(order = 2, dV = parm[1], dW = exp(parm[2:3]),
           m0 = c(level0, slope0),
           C0 = 400*diag(2))
    # Seasonal Term
    # Season Factor model
    # season <- dlmModSeas(frequency = 7, dW = c(parm[4], rep(0, 5)))
    # Fourier Form Seasonal Model
    season <- dlmModTrig(s = 7, q = 2, dW = rep(c(parm[4], parm[5]), each = 2))
    # ARMA Term
    arma <- dlmModARMA(ar = ARtransPars(parm[6:7]), ma = parm[8:9], sigma2 = parm[10])
    return(trend + season + arma)
}
# MLE for parameter estimation
init <- c(1e-07, -3, -1, 5, 4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 1)
fit_dlm <- dlmMLE(y, parm = init, build, hessian = TRUE)

dlmSales <- build(fit_dlm$par)
f1 <- dlmForecast(dlmSales, n = 16)
```

My first question is, in the math modeling, there should be only one observation error, indicating that, there also should be only one `dV` in the R model. So, I only used the `dV` argument in `dlmModPoly`, is this correct?

I know that MLE is not considered the best way for estimating unknown parameters. As I read the book `Dynamic Linear Model with R`, it also gives methods like Bayesian Inferences with discount factor (with/without time-variant `dV`) or Simulation-based Bayesian inference.

Here are my questions

- How do I use `dlmFilterDF` if my model consist of three parts, which is `mod <- dlmModPoly + dlmModTrig + dlmModARMA`? Can I do this `modFilt <- dlmFilterDF(y, mod, DF = 0.9)` directly? I think that Bayesian Inference assumes that Ft and Gt are known, but the AR and MA in my case are unknown parameters, so this method might not work?
- When applying `dlmGibbsDIG`, can I assign vectors to `a.theta` and `b.theta`? because the unknown parameters psi in my case is of length 6 (1 for dV, 2 for local linear `dW`, 2 for seasonality `dW`, 1 for ARMA `dW`). Also, the same concern as the question above, AR and MA are unknown parameters in my case, can they be estimated with Gibbs Sampling? Probably  Hybrid Sampling is a better choice, as suggested in section 4.6.1.

Comment: I have similar problem and can you assist me how to do the ARIMA model in state space using r?